# Bootstrap Formhelper

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, form-helpers, formhelper

I have added phone formatting to my bootstrap form helpers form, but am having trouble in getting the placeholder to show up. Before adding the form helper's formatting, the placeholder was appearing as usual, but after adding the formatting, it went away.

```
<input class="form-control bfh-phone" data-format=" (ddd) ddd-dddd"  id="sender_phone" name="sender_phone" type="text" value="<?php echo display_output($sender_phone)?>" />
```

Can someone help out? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I've realized that if I remove the parenthesis it will work. Thus a format such as XXX-XXX-XXXX won't yield the problem as opposed to using (XXX)-XXX-XXXX